# how to clear all tools in the vb.net from

Tags: vb.net

i have used many of the controls in vb.net forms, including a textbox and combobox, but I want to clear all my text boxes at once, while not typing textbox1.clear() for each one.
Is there any other way to clear all my textboxes?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you question right, you should be able to loop through all the controls on your form and check to see what Control type they are. Based on their type, either set the textbox Text property to String.Empty, or your ComboBox to the index of a blank ListItem (presumably item zero).

Something like:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then

        CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty

    Else

        ' do something similar for your ComboBox

    End If

Next
```